# Getting consistent pseudo columns in listboxes vba

Tags: windows, vba, vb6, controls, spacing

I am replacing the few instances of MSFlexgrid that appears in our companies VBA code for some old versions of AutoCAD. We have decided to replace them with listboxes. However we are unable to get a consistent spacing as far as the "columns" we are creating in our list boxes (we are just separating data with a pipe '|'). as the font does not have consistent letter widths, we are unable to pad with spaces as we had intended.

What should I try so that Listbox text is consistently padded?

also I don't particularly care which control we use, so feel free to suggest any other standard vb6 control

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your font for the ListBox to be a [Monospaced font](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font)

I personally prefer Courier New:

Change it in the Properties:
[image]